# Subtracting Two Case Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database: SQL Server

Hopefully this is really simple. I have a purchase order query and I am trying to subtract two case statements but I am having issues getting it to work. I am using temp tables to pull the purchase order data in.

See query below:

```
--temp table for PO Inventory lines
select 
prchseordr_id,
ISNULL (sum(prchseordrlst_cst_extndd),0) as Inv_Cost
INTO #TempPOInv

from prchseordr
left outer join prchseordrlst on prchseordr.prchseordr_rn = prchseordrlst.prchseordr_rn
where prchseordr_nxt_id = ''
group by prchseordr_id
--------------------
--temp table for PO General lines
select 
prchseordr_id,
ISNULL (sum(prchseordrlstgn_cst_extndd),0) as Gen_Cost
INTO #TempPOGen

from prchseordr
left outer join prchseordrlstgn on prchseordr.prchseordr_rn = prchseordrlstgn.prchseordr_rn
where prchseordr_nxt_id = ''
group by prchseordr_id
--------------------
--temp table for PO Subcontractor lines
select 
prchseordr_id,
ISNULL (sum(prchseordrlstsb_cntrct_amnt_orgnl),0) as Sub_Cost
INTO #TempPOSub

from prchseordr
left outer join prchseordrlstsb on prchseordr.prchseordr_rn = prchseordrlstsb.prchseordr_rn
where prchseordr_nxt_id = ''
group by prchseordr_id

------------------------------------------------------------
Select
vndr_nme as [Vendor Name],
sum(CASE WHEN prchseordr_type = 'Purchase' THEN Inv_Cost + Gen_Cost + Sub_Cost else 0 end ) Purchases,
sum(CASE WHEN prchseordr_type = 'Credit' THEN Inv_Cost + Gen_Cost + Sub_Cost else 0 end ) Credits
from prchseordr
left outer join #TempPOInv on prchseordr.prchseordr_id = #TempPOInv.prchseordr_id
left outer join #TempPOGen on prchseordr.prchseordr_id = #TempPOGen.prchseordr_id
left outer join #TempPOSub on prchseordr.prchseordr_id = #TempPOSub.prchseordr_id
join vndr on prchseordr.vndr_rn = vndr.vndr_rn
where prchseordr.prchseordr_entrd_dte between @DateStart@ and @DateEnd@
and prchseordr_rn <> 0
group by vndr_nme,prchseordr_type
order by vndr_nme 


DROP TABLE #TempPOInv
DROP TABLE #TempPOGen
DROP TABLE #TempPOSub
```

Pretty basic I just want to subtract the Purchases from the Credits to get the Net total of purchase orders. What is the best way to make this work?

Comment: Please include some sample data to illustrate what you're trying to do.  What are you trying to get as a result?

Comment: Considering that `prchseordr_type` cannot be both `Purchase` and `Credit` I don't see what you could be subtracting.  It seems like you're missing a grouping or some other mechanism.

Comment: On a side note to whichever answer you choose, you may want to add `ISNULL(..._Cost, 0)` (or something of the like) around your `..._Cost` columns if you might ever have `NULL` values in them. Otherwise a `NULL + AnyValue = NULL`.

Comment: You can treat `CASE ... END` just like any other expression. Thus, `CASE ... END - CASE ... END AS Difference` should work perfectly fine. Obviously, the CTEs suggested in the answers have the advantage of not needing to repeat the `CASE ... END` clauses if you need the two base values as well.

Comment: I posted the full query to the post as to make it more clear what I am working with.

Comment: Case expressions, not statements.

Comment: Woops. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch your case statement - you want to sum based on a case.

After that, the most readable would be to put it into a subquery or CTE, like:

```
select
    x.[Vendor Name]
    ,x.Credits - x.Purchases [Profit]
from
(
    Select
        vndr_nme as [Vendor Name],
        sum(CASE WHEN prchseordr_type = 'Purchase' THEN Inv_Cost + Gen_Cost + Sub_Cost else 0 end ) Purchases,
        sum(CASE WHEN prchseordr_type = 'Credit' THEN Inv_Cost + Gen_Cost + Sub_Cost else 0 end ) Credits
    From ...
) x
```

Or:

```
;with x as (
    Select
        vndr_nme as [Vendor Name],
        sum(CASE WHEN prchseordr_type = 'Purchase' THEN Inv_Cost + Gen_Cost + Sub_Cost else 0 end ) Purchases,
        sum(CASE WHEN prchseordr_type = 'Credit' THEN Inv_Cost + Gen_Cost + Sub_Cost else 0 end ) Credits
    From ...
)
select
    x.[Vendor Name]
    ,x.Credits - x.Purchases [Profit]
from x
```

Comment: I could not get CTE to work. I included the full query above.

Comment: I had a typo - that `x` after the closing paren shouldn't be there. Edited.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. I did not realize I needed the ; to keep everything separate. I was trying to make CTE work all morning. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Yep, the leading semi-colon is not required if it's the beginning of what you're running, but it's recommended because if there does happen to be something before it, the semi-colon will end the previous statement. One of the reasons I dislike optional semi-colons in any language (cough, cough, javascript).

Comment: Case expression, not statement.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways... one is CTE

```
;with cte as(
Select
vndr_nme as [Vendor Name],
sum(CASE WHEN prchseordr_type = 'Purchase' THEN Inv_Cost + Gen_Cost + Sub_Cost else 0 end ) Purchases,
sum(CASE WHEN prchseordr_type = 'Credit' THEN Inv_Cost + Gen_Cost + Sub_Cost else 0 end ) Credits
from prchseordr
left outer join #TempPOInv on prchseordr.prchseordr_id = #TempPOInv.prchseordr_id
left outer join #TempPOGen on prchseordr.prchseordr_id = #TempPOGen.prchseordr_id
left outer join #TempPOSub on prchseordr.prchseordr_id = #TempPOSub.prchseordr_id
join vndr on prchseordr.vndr_rn = vndr.vndr_rn
where prchseordr.prchseordr_entrd_dte between @DateStart@ and @DateEnd@
and prchseordr_rn <> 0
group by vndr_nme,prchseordr_type)

select 
    [Vendor Name],
    Purchases,
    Credits,
    Purchases - Credits as NewColumn
from cte
```

Comment: I could not get CTE to work. I updated the post to include the full query.

Comment: @AdrianWarness i edited my answer. Just replace that part of your code. Make sure you include the ; before the cte

Comment: I am an idiot! I have been trying to do a CTE all morning but I did not know about the ; to separate everything. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AdrianWarness the ; is only needed if a statement precedes it. If it is the first thing in your batch you don't need it. I'm glad you got it working.